# What are some Linux lightweight PDF alternatives that support tabs?

Tags: linux, pdf, tabs, viewer, lightweight

- Adobe Reader is the best, but it's so resource heavy. It takes almost 10% of my 8GB ram.
- Evince has trouble with highlighting text and does not support tabs.
- Foxit Reader for Linux does not support tabs.

Any assistance in choosing an appropriate PDF viewer that supports these features on Linux and isn't too resource intensive?

Thanks

Mahmoud

Comment: For reference, I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, but this is a generic Linux question

Answer (score 1):

If you have the KDE libraries installed, I suppose you could use Konqueror - it's really intended as a web browser, but it has tabs, and it can display PDFs using the Okular KPart.

Comment: Clever, slightly out of the box solution.  Nice.

Comment: Thanks ;-) but it's not so clever really, I'm actually just used to doing that myself. I haven't quite gotten out of the mindset of KDE 3, when Dolphin didn't exist and Konqueror served as the web browser, file manager, and generic viewer application all in one.